# Canon Printer Installations - Wish to locate a tutorial or step-by-step guide that works

Tags: drivers, 16.04, printing, canon

Ubuntu 16.04 Canon Printer installation problems...

The major obstacle to adopting Linux exclusively in my small business, is the monumental hassle, and apparent impossibility of a "regular joe" having any chance of getting any network printer working properly.

I have been at it for literally WEEKS now. And, the obstacles seem to be insurmountable. I have previously requested assistance with an Epson Laser LP-S5000. It seems no one has the answer for that... or isn't sharing.

Now, I have TWO Canon Inkjets that simply will not work as network printers. (iX6830 and MG6930) Both work with the computer they are directly connected to... One MacOS 10.11.6, one Ubuntu 16.04.

BELIEVE me... I have tried the network printer installation options offered in the system. I have tried to understand PPD files (But, cannot locate any for these printers) and ipp/dns connections. I have read about CUPS and Gutenprint. And, quite frankly am at a loss to understand how the writers could possibly expect someone without a computer science degree to comprehend it.

The only output I have been able to achieve is multiple pages with escape characters printed in the upper corners.

What I am looking for is someone who has already solved this problem... understands this problem... And, the location of a post or article with real answers as to how to do this. Otherwise, it is just impossible to install a network printer.

Linux simply cannot be a part of our lives if it cannot print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a fairly steep learning curve and a lot of searching, I have finally solved this problem. For the sake of posterity, I present the following.

First, I did not know that printer models were regionalized. I knew driver/software distros were region specific. But, I learned the actual models are restricted by region. (weird that)

Second, of course, my printers were Japanese models which is why I could not find drivers on any english websites... even Singapore.

Third, I found this page (http://cweb.canon.jp/cgi-bin/download/select-product-by-catg.cgi?i_cd_pr_catg=003) in Japanese that lists all the model numbers.
Drilling down from there is fairly easy until you find the Canon IJ LINUX (debian) package. Canon must have an English equivalent on their network somewhere.

(note**)... If installing a network printer, make sure it is already connected to the network with its own (manual) IP address. The printer's on-screen menu allows you to do that FIRST. If installing a local printer it must be directly connected and powered on first.

Fourth, after downloading/extracting the package, I had to learn that the installation was done using a shell script... (install.sh). Knowing absolutely nothing about this, I dove into the books and learned that using terminal to change into the directory holding the file and issuing; $ "sudo ./ install.sh" would start the script which asks a few simple questions (such as <1> Local Printer or <2> Network Printer) and actually FINDS and INSTALLS the (in my case) network printer... assuming it has been configured and actually appears on the network with its own IP.

Now, these Canon packages are available for a LARGE number of iP, iX, BJ, Pixus Inkjet printers. And, they MUST be somewhere on the Western Canon sites as well. Although I did note that the newest models do not have a linux package associated with them. Most notably the PixusPRO 10 and 100. Additionally, I learned that the iX6830 driver is actually a iX6800 SERIES package - and WORKS on anything within the 6800 number range... (North American too?) As it also, unexpectedly, found and installed my iX6850 on the same network.

I also downloaded the package for the MG6930, which is a 2016 model... The package IS available for that series as well. And, it also, works like a charm.

FIFTH and probably most important... SAVE those packages in a safe place in case you have to reinstall.

I know I am not the only noob here. And, it must be very difficult for the small number of "pros" here to keep up with helping everyone. So, hopefully, this will help the people who just want to know how to install a printer (at least a canon inkjet)
Thanks to everyone who had suggestions for me. Ultimately, any help is good help - as it helps drive us toward finding the solution for ourselves.

Enjoy the ride!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you come across this link yet? I looks like there might be a repo with drivers and according to some of the comments on the page, they got it working.

[Canon printers & linux](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/canon-drivers-for-ubuntu-and-linux-mint/)

Sorry in advance if you've already stumbled upon it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I had bookmarked that page. Unfortunately, my printer is not listed among the compatible devices.

Comment: I actually found a deb package for this printer located at 
cweb.canon.jp/drv-upd/ij-mfp/linux-pd-20152h-520.html

I installed the driver on my local Ubuntu machine... But, when I tried to install the network printer. There was no way to point it towards the new driver... The foomatic didn't list it, and no dialog is available to load the MG9630 driver... What in the world am I missing>